# Unable to import Scrapy Spider into Script

Tags: python, scrapy, python-import

All my imports are working except for importing `class` `SomeSpider` into `main/main.py` from `spider/src.py`. The spider itself runs when I call `scrapy crawl somespider` in the terminal. Does python not recognize `modules` with `scrapy.spider` ?

My file structure:

```
/whiskers
-/venv
--/bin
--/include
--/lib
--/whiskers
---/whiskers
----/main
-----/main.py
----/spiders
-----/__init__.py
-----/src.py
----/__init__.py
----/items.py
----/middlewares.py
----/pipelines.py
----/settings.py
---/scrapy.cfg
--/pyvenv.cfg
```

Putting any of these in `main/main.py`:

```
from whiskers.spiders.src import SomeSpider
   
(or) 

from whiskers.whiskers.spiders.src import SomeSpider

(or) 

from whiskers.venv.whiskers.whiskers.spiders.src import SomeSpider
```

gives error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'whiskers'
```

Trying either:

```
from ..spiders.src import SomeSpider

(or)

from .. import LawSpider
```

gives error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

In `spider/src.py` the spider itself is just a basic `scrapy.Spider` named `SomeSpider`:

```
class SomeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your `main.py` script outside a package folder. A package folder is a folder containing an `__init__.py`. The idea which Guido van Rossum had with this, is that scripts - the starting points, modules where `__name__ == '__main__'` - should not reside *inside* but *outside* of packages. Packages shall just contain library code which gets imported - into scripts or into other packages.

In this case, the simplest is to move the main.py two levels up:

```
whiskers/
  venv/
    bin/
    include/
    lib/
    whiskers/
      main.py  <-- put it here
      whiskers/
        __init__.py
        spiders/
          __init__.py
          src.py
        items.py
        middlewares.py
        pipelines.py
        settings.py
      scrapy.cfg
    pyvenv.cfg
```

Then in the main.py do `from whiskers.spiders.src import SomeSpider`.